# PHP If statement inside For loop

Tags: php, loops

The following code gives syntax error because of `IF`. How can I fix this without removing IF statement?

```
<?php
    for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++){ 
        $data .= 'h'.$i.'{'.    
            if ( !empty ($size) ) {.
            'font-size: ' .$size. ';'.
            }.
        '}';
    }
?>
```

**Error:**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use an `if` statement within an expression, because it is syntactically wrong and the statement itself doesn't return a value. Use the ternary `?:` operator which can be nested there:

```
$data .= 'h' . $i . '{' . (!empty($size) ? "font-size: $size" : '') . '}';
```

You could also benefit from the usage of double quotes to interpolate the variables instead of getting messy with the `.` operator.

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $data .= "h$i{" . (!empty($size) ? "font-size: $size;" : "") . "}";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `if` in string concatenation, but you can use shortcode:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++){ 
        $data .= 'h'.$i.'{'.(!empty($size) ? ('font-size: ' .$size. ';') : '').'}';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++){ 
    $data .= 'h'.$i.'{'.((!empty ($size))?'font-size: {$size}':'').'}';
}
```

Explanation:

The following construct is called "ternary if":

```
$x = ($test == "Y")?"Yes!":"No!";
```

and is the same as:

```
if ($test == "Y"){
  $x="Yes!";
} else {
  $x="No!";
}
```

Comment: @Yaroslav: I fixed the typo. Thanks. Now it actually works. I'll comment in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't string full-blown if's in-line, so either one of the following should fix this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++)
{//ternary
    $data .= 'h'.$i.'{'.( !empty ($size) ? 'font-size: ' .$size. ';' : '').'}';
}
```

Which is the same as writing:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++)
{
    $data .= 'h'.$i.'{';
    if (!empty ($size))
    {
        $data .= 'font-size: ' .$size. ';';
    }
    $data .= '}';
}
```

Well, to be 100% accurate, the ternary operator concats `''` if `$size` is empty. The ternary syntax is as follows: `[evaluate statement] ? [if true] : [else]`. So the truly full-blown equivalent of that code is:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++)
{
    $data .= 'h'.$i.'{';
    if (!empty ($size))
    {
        $data .= 'font-size: ' .$size. ';';
    }
    else
    {
        $data .= '';
    }
    $data .= '}';
}
```

Comment: `}` should be outside if statement

Comment: Your `else` statement has no meaning.

Comment: I added that to clarify the ternary operator: `? [if true] : [else]`, when written in full, you wouldn't include the else, but `?:` always needs a right side (else) statement, so transcribing the ternary in full leaves you with a pointless `else` statement, yes, but it's there

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be without error:

```
<?php
    for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++){ 
        $data .= 'h'.$i.'{' ;
            if ( !empty ($size) ) {
           $data .= 'font-size: ' .$size. ';';
            }
        $data .='}';
    }


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are in the middle of adding stuff to a string in the line starting with `$data`.

Two solutions:

1) Stop adding stuff, start your if, add more stuff inside, stop if, then add the rest in a new statement.

```
$data .= 'h'.$i.'{';

if ( !empty ($size) ) {.
    $data .= 'font-size: ' .$size. ';'.
}.

$data .= '}';
```

1. Use the ternary operator.

`$data .= 'h'.$i.'{' (!empty($size) ? 'font-size: ' .$size. ';' : ''). '}';`

The ternary operator evaluates the first argument to either true or false and returns the second or third argument, just like a function call.

Beware: Using ternary operators too much will make your code unreadable, especially when using it inside each other. You can always replace it with a separated IF construct like above for better readability. Plus the ternary operator cannot be easily extended to do more stuff besides returning one of two values.